# Azure continuous webjob stopping after couple of hours

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am using a continuous webjob mode of deployment of azure-webjobs. The requirement here for me is : I need the webjob to run continuously, currently the webjob stops after ~2 hours without any exception detected, so it has to be azure that is stopping the webjob. The webjob is a C# console application, and does not use the WebJobs SDK (A solution without using the SDK is preferred). The application also outputs to the console, so the possibility of CPU being idle is also out.

I have tried all the settings for webjob :

- ALWAYS ON = ON.
- SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT = 172800 secs (48 hours).
- WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT =  172800 secs (48 hours).

These settings are for triggered jobs, but just tried if that could help, but no luck. Appreciate all the help I could get here, or if anyone has faced a similar problem.

Comment: Which web app plan does your WebJob hosted? Free/Shared or others?

Comment: @Amor-MSFT The app plan is on the standard tier

Comment: Could you tell us what you did in your WebJob? Is your code run completely after 2 hours. Normally, continuous webjob will restart after the WebJob stopped. Was your WebJob restarted?

Comment: What are you seeing (if anything) in the WebJob logs?

Comment: It shows the webjob directory has been changed and stopped as a result.

Comment: Were you ever able to get your WebJob to run longer than 2 hours @Tom?

Comment: Woul love to have an answer from @Tom too !